# Upload Secret File to Vercel for Use in Next.js Application

Tags: vercel

How do I upload a secret file, e.g. containing a .pem key, to Vercel for use in my next.js application? Clearly I don't want that in a git repo.

Comment: hey @reno, did you got the answer for this?